# Parsing a CSV quoted string CSV file in Perl using split

Tags: regex, perl

I have a CSV file in the format shown below, and I'm using the Perl `split` command as shown, based on comma as delimiter.   The problem is I have a quoted string `"HTTP Large, GMS, ZMS: Large Files"` with embedded commas and it fails. The array values will have only less elements.  How can I modify the split command.

```
  my @values = split('\,', $line);
```

**CSV File**

```
 10852,800 Mob to Int'l,235341739,573047,84475.40,0.0003,Inbound,Ber unit
 10880,"HTTP Large, GMS, ZMS: Large Files",52852810,128,13712.68,0.0002,,Rer unit
 13506,Presence National,2716766818,2447643,309116.40,0.0001,Presence,per Cnit
```

Comment: Your question begs the question - why not use (e.g.) the [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module instead, which handles this sort of gotcha for you?

Comment: One lesson all programmers should learn: Never parse CSV or HTML all by yourself. Use the existing modules, they are usually mature, stable and well tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues like embedded commas are precisely why modules such as [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) were created.  If, but only if, the data does not have embedded commas, then you can make regular expressions work.  When the data has embedded commas, it is time to move to a tool designed to handle CSV with embedded commas, and that would be `Text::CSV` in Perl (and its relatives [`Text::CSV_PP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_PP) and [`Text::CSV_XS`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS)).

Comment: which i need to use Text::CSV_PP or Text::CSV_XS? What is the difference? Will it work on perl, v5.8.7 built for sun4-solaris-64-ld

Comment: You use and install `Text::CSV`; it comes with the pure Perl implementation, `Text::CSV_PP` (the `_PP` suffix indicates 'pure Perl', not needing a C compiler).  Then to wring the most performance out of your system, you install `Text::CSV_XS`, which uses the Perl extension mechanism and C code functions to implement a higher-speed version of the same code.  `Text::CSV` has been around since before there was Perl 5.8; it will work fine with 5.8.7.  The current maintainer's first release was in 2007, though.  (Searching through my private archives, I found Text-CSV-0.01.tar.gz from July 1997.)

Answer (score 1):

I have also used the same approach as yours and it works fine with me. Try this code.

```
my @values = split(/(?<="),(?=")/, $line);
```

hope it helps

Comment: Your code breaks on the OP's data, and on this: `1234,"What happens when you have a embedded "","" in your file?","Does it break?"` If you just use `Text::CSV` module you know it will return the correct resutls.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu I got your point but I only suggested my option based on he's example and code. Correction based on his question which is split.